# Show JFrames on client side

Tags: java, swing, file-upload, jframe, japplet

I've created an upload file functionality on my system. This is made by using JFrames.

- Here's the first Frame:
  [image: http://i.imgur.com/znrUWaw.jpg?3]
- Second Frame
  [image: http://i.imgur.com/dBQZ0cZ.jpg?1]

**My problem is:**
I need this to show on the client side. I know it will show on the server side.
I also know that I need to use applet instead of this, but how?

I want it to be like Oracle E-business suite. When I click a link a java application window will pop-out.

Do Oracle E-business suite using applet or something else?

Comment: Applets come to mind, but they would need to be signed to allow access to the clients file system. [Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/) is another possibility...

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your quick response! Are you familiar with E-Business Suite of Oracle? I want my upload file to be like that. When I open a page or click a link a java application window will pop-out. does oracle e-business suite use applet or something else? @MadProgrammer

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Note that JWS provides the JNLP API that can make it possible for even sand-boxed apps. to read files from the local file-system.  [GIFanim](http://pscode.org/gifanim/) is an example (that is deployed as both an applet and frame). So.. 'two birds with one stone'.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)